# jersey (+ jackson) map field serialization

Tags: json, jaxb, jersey, jackson

I have a simple jersey web service and I'd like to consume / produce objects that contain map fields, like

```
@XmlElement
private Map<String,String> properties;
```

if this string goes into the web service,

```
{ properties: { key1: val1, key2: val2 )}
```

the properties field is deserialized as null with no errors. the same JSON goes in and out of GSON no problems, and in the short term I solved this by having jersey consume produce strings and using GSON to serialize / deserialize the JSON.

any ideas?

Comment: Ever hear of JSON? You just recreated it ;) Though you tagged it as such ... what's the question, exactly? There are a number of JSON parsers for Java

Comment: Please don't insult people. That won't get you very far.

Comment: @BrianRoach If you read the question properly, Jeffrey has mentioned the term 'GSON'. Gson is a Java library that can be used to convert Java Objects into their JSON representation. So the question here is a little more sophisticated than pulling out a JSON parser from a Google search and use it.

Comment: @VikramBodicherla - See that thing up there that says "Edited Apr 10" ... maybe you might want to pay attention to that sort of thing in the future before spouting off. Clicking on it will show you what the question looked like when I commented on it.

Comment: @BrianRoach Sorry my bad. But why are you so jumpy man! With all the sarcasm!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jersey uses JAXB for serialization. JAXB can not serialize a Map as there is no XML type for Java type Map. Also, Map is an interface and JAXB does not like interfaces.
If you are using JAXBJackson bridge to marshal, you will run into issue.

You will need to create an adapter like below and annotate your Map property with

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MapAdapter.class)
private Map<String,String> properties;

@XmlSeeAlso({ Adapter.class, MapElement.class })
public class MapAdapter<K,V> extends XmlAdapter<Adapter<K,V>, Map<K,V>>{


  @Override
  public Adapter<K,V> marshal(Map<K,V> map) throws Exception {

    if ( map == null )
      return null;

    return new Adapter<K,V>(map);
  }


  @Override
  public Map<K,V> unmarshal(Adapter<K,V> adapter) throws Exception {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unmarshalling a list into a map is not supported");
  }

  @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
  @XmlType(name="Adapter", namespace="MapAdapter")
  public static final class Adapter<K,V>{

    List<MapElement<K,V>> item;

    public Adapter(){}

    public Adapter(Map<K,V> map){
      item = new ArrayList<MapElement<K,V>>(map.size());
      for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        item.add(new MapElement<K,V>(entry));
      }      
    }
  }

  @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
  @XmlType(name="MapElement", namespace="MapAdapter")
  public static final class MapElement<K,V>{

    @XmlAnyElement
    private K key;

    @XmlAnyElement
    private V value; 

    public MapElement(){};

    public MapElement(K key, V value){
      this.key = key;
      this.value = value;
    }

    public MapElement(Map.Entry<K, V> entry){
      key = entry.getKey();
      value = entry.getValue();
    }

    public K getKey() {
      return key;
    }

    public void setKey(K key) {
      this.key = key;
    }

    public V getValue() {
      return value;
    }

    public void setValue(V value) {
      this.value = value;
    }


  }

}
```

Comment: thanks. i've moved on to use GSON at this point, but good information.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use annotated classes. So for instance a user might be represented by the following data.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
public class User { 
    private int uid;
    public int user_id;
    public String user_name;
    public String email;
    public URI image_url;
    public List<User> friends;
    public boolean admin;

    public User() {
        ...
    }
    public User(final int userid) {
        // Find user by id
    }
}
```

If you return the User object as in the following piece of code, then jaxb will automatically serialize the List as a JSON list etc etc....

```
@GET
@Path("/{userid}")
@Produces("application/json", "application/xml")
    public User showUser(@PathParam("userid") final int userid) {
        return new User(userid);
}
```

Comment: thanks but the question is about how to correctly pass an object with a map field. jersey + jackson doesn't want to serialize / deserialize that. i'll try to edit the question to make that more clear.

Comment: You mean pass in an Object type? Jersey+Jackson can't handle that. You need to define what values are in the object.

Comment: well ... no. the java object to be serialized / deserialized simply has a field that's a map.

Comment: Are you sure that you're filling the map with values? If there are no values then it will be serialized as a null object.

Comment: the map comes in as json. i replaced jackson w/ GSON, and it works fine, so i assume it's valid. i tried permuting the format of the json in various ways, but i still get null. regardless, if the json is invalid, jackson should tell me so.