# returning json serialized MAP<String,String> from jersey RESTFUL Service

Tags: json, serialization, annotations, jaxb, jersey

I want to return a json answer that looks like this:

```
{ "key": "value",
  "Key2": "value2",
  "params": {"paramKey1":"ParamValue1",
             "paramKey2":"ParamValue2",
             "paramKeyN":"ParamValueN"
            }
}
```

where the keys and values of params are from a `MAP<String,String>`
i.e. - The class to be serialized should support an unknown number of params & respective values.

I tried having in my class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class myclass {

private int key;
private int key2;

private Map<String,String> _params;

@XmlElement
public int getKey() {
    return key;
}

@XmlElement
public int getKey2() {
    return key2;
}


@XmlElement
public HashMap<String,String> getParams() {
    return (HashMap<String,String>)_params;
}

}
```

but it does not render the params map, only:

```
{ "key": "value",
  "Key2": "value2",
  "params": null
}
```

I think that I need to annotate getParams with something else but I am not sure what...

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556853/jersey-jackson-map-field-serialization

Comment: I will have to try it out, however It does not seem as if the OP of that Q actually used the answer he got and validated it.
he just said that he switched to gson - without actually explaining how this helped resolve the issue.

Comment: well, by default `jersey` using `jackson` to serialize/deserialize fields and properties. You could just use gson for same purposes.

Comment: even though you may be right, I have no idea how to do that :(
for now I also found my way around it by converting the map to a `String[]` set with `["key","value,"key2","value2"...]` and converting the array back to an object in the Javascript side.
That said, I would still like to know how to use maps for this.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the variable name of `_params` to `params`. This fails JAXB naming conventions, as I can remember and might cause the error.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will have to look into it and see if this helps. seeing however that As I stated above I did find my way around the issue for now, It might time some time until I revisit this issue.